# electric circuity- data capture from visual representation

Tags: graph-theory

For an electrical circuitry example, I am creating an ability to drop elements(wire, resistor, battery) on a 10X10 grid. I need to be able to capture elements dropped and identify closed loops and junctions from the grid.

Any ideas of how I can internally capture this and process- essentially would need to know programatically on vertices and closed loops formed by them. I read that this falls under graph theory- any thoughts on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Steven S. Skiena's "Algorithm Design Manual" has great details on graph algorithms.  Maybe it can help you.  It's a great book to have under any circumstance.

Comment: Thanks- should I be looking at graph theory or is there a simpler way to capture and process this?

Comment: Nothing simpler - it's a network, a graph, a circuit.  What else would you expect?

Comment: got a great lead and wanted to update the community- standardized algorithm called modified nodal analysis, apparently takes care of the bulk of the heavy lifting. Still under implementation